# Handling click and hover on same element and keeping the popup modal opened till the time popup modal is hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, mouseevent

I have implemented click and hover functionaly over an element , from presvious answer I had tackled the popup position relative to mousepointer.
But now I want to fix the popup modal position when hovered on say vertically middle by the side wrt the hovered element.

Issue when I hover on the element the popup modal starts flickering and when I click in some other place within the element somehow then the modal opens up finally.

**Onclick**

To show the popup modal in full screen when clicked on(*this thing works but not in the correct way,flickering thing*) + when popup modal being hovered it should be kept open.
Once the popup modal is opened the popup modal can only be closed once click happens anywhere outside of the modal

**OnHover**

To show the popup modal fixed vertically centre by the side wrt the hovered element(*this thing as well works but positioning is not correct*) +
when popup modal being hovered it should be kept opened.
In this case as soon as the mouse leaves from the element or from the popup modal , the popup modal should close.

**Minimum Reproducible Example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yybbgm?file=src/app/app.component.html

app.component.html

```
<div class="box"
  (mouseenter)="addClickEvent($event)"
  (mouseleave)="addClickEvent($event)"
  (mousemove)="addClickEvent($event)"
  (click)="addClickEvent($event)">
</div>

<fs-modal *ngIf="modalShow"
           [ngStyle]="{'top.px': (zoneIsClicked ? 0 : modaltop) ,
                   'left.px':(zoneIsClicked ? 0 : modalleft)}"
           [ngClass]="zoneIsClicked ? 'zoneClicked' : 'zoneNotClicked'">
</fs-modal>
```

app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
name = 'Angular';

modalShow = false;
modalleft;
modaltop;
zoneIsClicked;

addClickEvent(e) {
 if(e.type === 'click'){
  this.modalShow = true;
  this.zoneIsClicked = true;
 }
/*else if (e.type === 'mousemove') {
  this.modalleft = e.clientX
  this.modaltop = e.clientY
}*/
else if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
  this.modalShow = true;
  this.zoneIsClicked = false;
  this.modalleft = e.clientX
  this.modaltop = e.clientY
}
else if (e.type === 'mouseleave') {
  this.modalShow = false;
}
}

}
```

app.component.css

```
.box{
width: 100px;       
height: 100px;      
background: rgba(254, 249, 247, 1);     
border: 1.5px solid #e24301;        
margin: 50px;       
font-size: 0.8rem;
position: absolute; 
}

.zoneClicked{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 900px;
}

.zoneNotClicked{
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
}
```

fsmodal.component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'fs-modal',
  template: `<div [ngStyle]="{'border':'1px solid black'}">ok</div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class fsModalComponent  {
}
```

Comment: you want to place it in vertically center of the box when you click. right?

Comment: @DeepuReghunath , yes , just on the right side of the box , thanks

Comment: hi , it is not correctly positioned if I have more than one boxes then it is not positioned on the right side of the box as for the single box , please suggest

Comment: what is the expected behavior? like, on hover, the popup needs to open and when the mouse moves off, the pop-up disappears?

Comment: Yeah this link it is working but positioning is not in a dynamic way https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emrzkv?file=src/app/app.component.ts , link by @DeepuReghunath

Comment: @NidhinJoseph, I mean if I have more than one boxes then it is not woking and for single box as well I have add some 210px like this =  this.modalleft = e.target.clientWidth +  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e.target).getPropertyValue('margin-left')) + 210;

Comment: It works for the 1st box but when I try to hover on 2nd box then the popup comes on top that , not on the right side as in case with 1st box

Comment: first issue is, `box` is `position: absolute;`, so multiple boxes will overlap. Try removing that and then add multiple boxes, works for me

Comment: @NidhinJoseph But after that also for the 2nd box the popup comes on the top of the 2nd box

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Can you please suggest if it can be done using :after

Comment: I am still confused with the requirement. Help me out here, when hover, where should the pop up come? like in the screenshot, is it right side? and on click, where should the pop up come? is it on top on the element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198982/discussion-between-enthu-and-nidhin-joseph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getBoundingClientRect()` to find exact position of the hovered element and set those values to your popup. Please find the demo below.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-du8pre?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: sure, will check shortly.

Comment: Sure mate, let me get some time and ill get it done.

Comment: ok thank you :) , I have accepted , I have tried but was not able to resolve

Answer (score 3):

Make some changes in your ts file. Remove the `mousemove` event for the box and handle the `mouseleave` event of box div

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkve7b?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: The popup comes up on hover and on click as well(now in my stackblitz link),but I want to fix popup's position just outside on the right edge of the box(like a tooltip) when hovered , and when box is clicked upon then I want to display the popup in full width and height and in both the scenarios to not close the popup when popup is being hovered upon .Hope now I am clear , thanks

Comment: ok the hover places the modal to the right , but when I try to enter in the modal it closes , how can we tackle this ,as I have asked in my question and when clicked then it opens on the right side where as it needs to take the full width,height screen and open on top of the box as mentioned in my post , thanks for your answer , I have also posted a screenshot

Comment: see the final solution. [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkve7b?file=src/app/app.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkve7b?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yeah it is somewhat working :) , but when I hover and when popup comes up then I try to go inside that popup and it goes off as mouseleaves triggers , till the time I am hovering over the box or over the popup the popup should stay , thanks

Comment: And also when the box is clicked , can I make the popup take full browser width and height

Comment: And I think the popup disappearing issue is there , due to the mouseleave event , how can we tackle that , like until and unless I am inside the box(that is working) or inside the opened modal popup,  the popup should not close (not working)

Comment: if you avoid mouseleave event for box and add it to the popup then the popup will remain there until a mouseleave event trigger on it. see this [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nysjdr?file=src/app/app.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nysjdr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198962/discussion-between-enthu-and-deepu-reghunath).

Comment: hi , it is not correctly positioned if I have more than one boxes then it is not positioned on the right side of the box as for the single box , please suggest

Comment: Rest all things are working but positioning not in full dynamic way

Comment: @Enthu Use `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` to calculate element position [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1bunyt?file=src/app/app.component.html](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1bunyt?file=src/app/app.component.html)